# Looping through this returned array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason, I cannot wrap my head around this one, and Google isn't playing fair right now.

What I am trying to do is call a .php file from another server with `$get_stream_addresses = file_get_contents('http://ip/transcode.php')`. The .php file will query the database and return the results.

**.php function on SERVER 1**

```
static function get_addresses($stream_id) {

    $get_stream_addresses = DB::select('SELECT * FROM stream_addresses WHERE stream_id = ?',
        array($stream_id));


    $i = 0;
    foreach($get_stream_addresses as $stream_address) {
        $i++;
        $stream_addresses[$i] = array(
            'url' => $stream_address->url,
            'bitrate' => $stream_address->bitrate,
            'v_height' => $stream_address->v_height,
            'v_width' => $stream_address->v_width
        );
    }

    return $stream_addresses;

}
```

The above outputs:

```
{"1":{"url":"999_high","bitrate":"2500","v_height":"720","v_width":"1280"},"2":{"url":"999_medium","bitrate":"1000","v_height":"480","v_width":"854"},"3":{"url":"999_low","bitrate":"600","v_height":"360","v_width":"640"}}
```

What I need to do is loop through $get_stream_addresses:

Something like

```
foreach($get_stream_addresses as $stream_address) {
     $stream_url = $stream_address['url'];
}
```

Comment: are you running that through `json_decode()` to turn it back into an array?

Comment: I am now... :)I played around with json_decode(), but I implemented it incorrectly. Now that you mentioned it, the light turned on, and all works great with my foreach, I call $stream_address->url. Thanks!

Comment: I've moved your answer in the question to an answer proper - feel free to edit it. Just noticed the string URL could do with some quotes around it, would you fix? (If you would prefer to add your own answer, please do, then ping me and I'll delete my wiki copy).

Comment: Yes, I forgot the quotes in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

In the question comments, Castis helped to turn the lightbulb on. I needed to use this:

```
$get_stream_addresses = json_decode(
   file_get_contents('http://ip/transcode.php')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($get_stream_addresses as $stream_address) {
     $stream_urls[] = $stream_address->url;
}
```

This will give you a simple array of all the URLs—assuming that is what you want.